# How to set -ms-touch-action: none; using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In a Windows Phone app I want to overwrite the default touch actions on the browser window so the events instead gets handled by the javascript.

From what I can read this can be done by setting `-ms-touch-action: none;` in the CSS of the homepage.. Unfortunately I can't change the CSS so instead I'm looking for a way to set `-ms-touch-action: none;` using the Invokescript javascript function of the browser..

Is this possible??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only JavaScript you could do it like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elem"); //body or what element you want.
elem.setAttribute("style","-ms-touch-action: none;");
```

Comment: You sir are a star been trying to do that for hours... thank you very much... I ended up just using `document.body.setAttribute("style","-ms-touch-action: none;");` because I wanted it on the hole page...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
document.body.style.msTouchAction = "none";
```

Answer (score 2):

Before using

```
document.body.style.msTouchAction = "none";
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767313.aspx).

Note:As of Internet Explorer 11, the Microsoft vendor prefixed version of this event `(-ms-touch-action`) is no longer supported and may be removed in a future release. Instead, use the non-prefixed name touch-action, which is better for standards compliance and future compatibility.

Comment: thank you will implement both and be on the safe side in a future update of the app....